# Uploading images into a folder

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am trying to upload multiple files into a folder and save the name of the files into a database.  My code is not working for uploading files into a folder.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into pictures (PictureName) VALUES('$file_name'); ";
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: File is not uploading... does your form have a valid enctype and is POST method?

Comment: add to your html form this : `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: @Fred-ii  Yes my is having  valid enctype and post method

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: i have updated my form code above

Comment: `$file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];` that should most likely read as `$file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];` why is there a `$key.` at the beginning?

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$tmp_name`, that's just a stray variable.

Comment: could u please tell me what i have to write

Comment: Have a look at this http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL - Pretty sure you'll get your answer in there. Plus, it seems like it's using the same tmp variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using for loop and storing the current image in the database and moving it

```
$image_array = $_FILES['files']['name'];
$tmp_array = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'];
for ($move_files=0; $move_files < count($image_array); $move_files++) { 
        $image = "$desired_dir/".$image_array[$move_files];
        $tmp_image = $tmp_array[$move_files];
//do other stuff like checking if image exists
    code here
//
 $query="INSERT into pictures (PictureName) VALUES('$image'); ";
 $db-exec($query); 
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_image, $image);
     }
```